# Why am I getting a Mass Assignment Error when I'm using Attr_Accessable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mass-assignment

I'm trying to write the ability for the admin to upload a CSV full of Judges.  I'm getting an AssignmentError when I try and do this.  This is really confusing to me, as I've used attr_accessible on all the relevant variables.  All the research I've done suggests that if you use attr_accessible, you should be able to mass assign variables.

I'm still a rails newbie, so excuse me if I'm doing something really dumb.

Test CSV:

```
Name,Email,Competition_ID,Password
Brandon Schultz,b@schultz.com,1,12345678
Mr. Foo,foo@foo.com,1,12345678
Mr. Bar,bar@bar.com,1,12345678
```

Error Message:

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in JudgesController#import
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: Name, Email, Competition_ID, Password
```

Application Trace:

```
app/models/judge.rb:17:in `block in import'
app/models/judge.rb:16:in `import'
app/controllers/judges_controller.rb:32:in `import'
```

Here's the relevant model:

```
class Judge < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :name, :competition_id

  belongs_to :competition

def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
            Judge.create! row.to_hash
        end
    end
end
```

Relevent Controller:

```
def import
  Judge.import(params[:file])
  redirect_to admin_portal_path, notice: "Products imported."
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hash that `row.to_hash` gives you will look like this:

```
{ 'Name' => 'Mr. Foo', 'Email' => 'foo@bar.com', ... }
```

The problem here is that the keys are strings that are capitalized. 'Email' != 'email'.

If you are passing the hash directly to `create!`, it needs to conform to the attribute names exactly, either as strings or symbols:

```
{ 'name' => 'Mr. Foo', :email => 'foo@bar.com', ... }
```

You should sanitize the keys to be snake_case (the same as their respective accessible attributes) before passing them to `create!`, or change them in the CSV.

You might also consider assigning each attribute individually from the row hash, and assigning a default value if it a value is not found.

```
hash = row.to_hash
judge = Judge.new
judge.name = hash['Name'] || hash['name'] || 'No name'
judge.email = hash['Email'] || hash['email']
judge.competition_id = hash['Competition_ID'] || hash['competition_id']
```

This is probably not the best thing to do in this case, but it can make your import script be much more robust if you are not in strict control over the format of the CSV files. It also gives you the opportunity to sanitize the values before writing them into your database.

Comment: I had a very similar problem. In my case my csv had a space after the comma and the data. For example: name, city, state.... instead of: name,city,state...I found the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19159125/964018)