# Cant mass assign protected attributes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Controller:

```
class HorsesController < ApplicationController
    require 'csv'

    def index
        @horses = Horse.all
    end

    def import
        Horse.import(params[:file])
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end
```

model:

```
class Horse < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :place

  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
        Horse.create! row.to_hash       
    end
  end
end
```

I have a CSV file that has two columns of data title name and place. When I try to import the file I get an error that says: `Can't mass-assign protected attributes:  place`

I seems to accept *:name* fine but for some reason will not work with *:place*???

Any help appreciated

Comment: Just wondering, is your csv file formatted like `name, place` instead of `name,place`? I'm wondering if the place is begin read as `<space>place` instead of `place`.

Comment: GAH! yes it is... thanks mate

Comment: Lol. I've had that happen to me before. Occam's Razor at its finest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your csv file formatted like `name, place` instead of `name,place`. `place` is begin read as `<space>place` instead of `place` which makes rails throw that error.

Comment: Thank you! I spend hours troubleshooting this issue for the exact same problem. This is one of those maddening little errors that you learn once and hopefully never forget. Appreciate the answer.